# Unable to run Coverage with Karma

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, karma-runner

I'm trying to run coverage with karma, and I get the warning: WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "coverage", it is not registered!

I thought I installed coverage when I ran 'npm install -g karma-coverage --save-dev'

Here's my config file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({
        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
                bunch of files..
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // use dots reporter, as travis terminal does not support escaping sequences
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // CLI --reporters progress
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        junitReporter: {
          // will be resolved to basePath (in the same way as files/exclude patterns)
          outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
        },

        // web server port
        // CLI --port 9876
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        // CLI --colors --no-colors
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        // CLI --log-level debug
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        // CLI --auto-watch --no-auto-watch
        autoWatch: true,

        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera
        // - Safari (only Mac)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows)
        // CLI --browsers Chrome,Firefox,Safari
        browsers: ['ChromeCanary'],

        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        // CLI --capture-timeout 5000
        captureTimeout: 20000,

        // Auto run tests on start (when browsers are captured) and exit
        // CLI --single-run --no-single-run
        singleRun: true,

        // report which specs are slower than 500ms
        // CLI --report-slower-than 500
        reportSlowerThan: 500,

        // compile coffee scripts
        preprocessors: {
            'someFileName': ['coverage'],
        },

        plugins: [
          'karma-jasmine',
          'karma-chrome-launcher',
          'karma-firefox-launcher',
        ],

    coverageReporter: {
        'type' : 'cobertura',
        'dir': 'coverage/'
    }

  });
};
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? One thing that I noticed sometimes throws things for a loop is global vs local install. Often times I have had to use a "npm link" to get things to work. ie: npm link karma-coverage in this instance. Also, I do think you really need to have "karma-coverage" in your plugin list.

Answer (score 54):

I got the same [WARN] because the plugin 'karma-coverage' was not defined inside the plugins of the config, try to see if adding it fixes your warning, not sure if it will fix your full problem.

```
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
],
```

UPDATE:
I also had a different problem when running the coverage, caused by istanbul, my error was

[coverage]: [TypeError: Cannot set property 'covered' of undefined]

After having a look what istanbul was doing it turned out that the paths to some of my js unit files were outdated in the **preprocessors**.

It was doing some of the coverage reports but it was not generating deep coverage reports for all files hence the error.  Once I fixed the paths it was all good.

```
    preprocessors : {
        '**/app/js/*/*.js' : 'coverage',
        '**/app/js/modules/*/*.js' : 'coverage',
        '**/app/js/services/*/*.js' : 'coverage'
    },
```

Comment: If you are running a globally installed karma node package, then all the other karma plugins must be installed globally as well; If you are running a project local karma, you need to ensure other karma plugins are locally installed for your project. Having locally karma plugins and launching a globally installed karma will result in 'karma-coverage'-not-registred type of error as well.

Comment: In my case all I had to do is run "npm install karma-coverage" (not even plugin section was required)

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, this works fine for me. Installed with:

```
npm install -g karma
npm install -g karma-coverage
```

Config in `karma.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['app.js','tests.js'],
    preprocessors: { 'app.js': 'coverage' },
    reporters: ['dots', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Run with `karma start karma.config.js`.

Comment: fwiw this does not produce coverage output for me.

Comment: Usually `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` I think.

Comment: @FutuToad I believe if you run npm install -g as root, they will goto /usr/local/. Otherwise they should be going to /home/user/, otherwise known as ~/. The advised method for running node, npm, nvm, ruby, and rvm are all as a non-root user.

Comment: Why app.js for the preprocessor?  Was this for express framework?

Comment: No, it just happened that in this example I had one "production" file, which happened to be called "app.js". The preprocessor line says to use the 'coverage' preprocessor on the 'app.js' file. Usually you'd provide a pattern like "*spec.js" there instead of just one file.

Answer (score 10):

For those who are using grunt test to run the karma test, and have the problem of coverage plugin not loaded issue. Please add the `plugins` setting into your Gruntfiles.js karama task, i.e.

```
// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true,
    plugins:[
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Solution with no global install

Install `karma-coverage`:

```
npm install --saved-dev karma-coverage
```

Then edit `karma.conf.js` and add `require('karma-coverage')` to the array of `plugins`.

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // ...
    plugins: [
      require('karma-coverage'), // ADD THIS
      // ...
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, I did not want the global install, this worked for me, thx.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, until I moved karma.conf.js into the same directory as package.json, then it worked.

Comment: I have them in the same dir but I am still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct solution is

**DON'T install karma globally**

INSTALL karma-cli globally and install karma locally

`npm i -g karma-cli`

> That's the problem then, you should use karma-cli globally, http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html
>   If you install karma globally it doesn't use the local installation.

reference: [github](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1488#issuecomment-120363831)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069183/karma-throws-error-can-not-load-ng-html2js-it-is-not-registered/19069377#19069377).

When using a globally installed karma it doesn't load the locally installed plugins. Using `node_modules/.bin/karma` to start the tests should solve this problem.

The installation of the coverage module in the global "namespace" also works but is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this issue with Angular 13. Install `karma-coverage` and here's the full config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/project-name'),
      reporters: [
        {
          type: 'html',
        },
        {
          type: 'lcov',
        },
        {
          type: 'text-summary',
        },
      ],
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    singleRun: false,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed karma-coverage globally it worked for me :-)

```
npm install -g karma-coverage
```

Comment: This worked for me... by why? I don't want to install it globally.