# Karma throws error: Can not load "ng-html2js", it is not registered

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, ng-html2js

I'm getting an error when I run `karma start`:

```
$ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "ng-html2js", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

...
```

But in my package file I have `"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "*",` and the folder with code for this preprocessor exists in `node_modules`.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Just in case, try to navigate to the folder containing your `package.json` and do an `npm install` there.

Comment: package.json placed in root

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In my cases, the problem was connected to lack of `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` inside karma config `plugins` sections. In tutorials I saw that you don't need to add `'ng-html2js'` inside plugins, but for me it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Code sample would be nice. Worked for me, though.

Answer (score 23):

If you are starting and running a global install of Karma, one that's installed with `-g` flag, and is run without specifying a path, i.e. `karma start path/to/config.js`, then make sure the plugins are also globally installed, i.e. `npm install -g karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor`.

If you're running a local install of Karma, i.e. `path/to/karma start path/to/config.js` then make sure plugin is also installed locally to that application.

Comment: yes, plugins installed locally for application. And I execute `karma run` from the root of application.

Comment: I think when you do `karma run` from root, you're actually running the global install of karma. Do you have it globally installed as well?

Comment: no, i'm sure i using local versions because of references in webstorm

Comment: Try to install everything globally, karma and all of its plugins. See if that helps.

Comment: Also, make sure your karma-config.js file has something like `preprocessors: {'tpl/*.html': 'ng-html2js'}`.

Comment: In order to use a local copy of karma, I put `"test": "karma start",` in the script section in my package.json

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Loading Plugins](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/plugins.html) in the docs.

If you omit the `plugins` property, it'll try to load all the plugins that are:

1. Prefixed with `karma-`.
2. A sibling to the `karma` npm module.

So if your file structure is:

```
- node_modules
  - karma
  - karma-chrome-launcher
  - karma-firefox-launcher
```

...since `karma-chrome-launcher` and `karma-firefox-launcher` are siblings to the `karma` module that is in use, and since they both start with `karma-` they'll be loaded automatically.

---

But be careful - if you *do* have the `plugins` property defined, it'll *only* load the things that are defined. Ie. if you have `plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher']`, it won't load `karma-firefox-launcher`.

---

Some questions to ask yourself:

1. Are you using a local version of `karma` or a global version?
2. Is everything up to date? If not try `npm update` or `npm uninstall` -> `npm install`.
3. Do you have global versions of `karma-x` that are overriding the local ones?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen too many different types of answers about this. And I had to try to out all the different methods to finally understand what was going on. I didn't have a `plugins:` section in my `karma.conf.js` either.

So I have a project `AwesomeKarmaTests` which contains all the files inside inside a folder of the same name.

```
AwesomeKarmaTests
\package.json
\karma.conf.js
\node_modules
            \karma
            \karma-jasmine
            ...
```

The `node_modules` directory is obviously going to be created when you `cd AwesomeKarmaTests` and run `npm install`.

`npm` would then go through the contents of the `package.json` in the folder from which it was invoked and install all the packages listed and further dependencies if required.

Contents of my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeKarmaTests",
  "version": "1.0.0",      
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

I encountered this problem (`Can not load "ng-html2js"`) initially because `karma` was installed **globally** in my system. The **global** `karma` installation would try to look for `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` package globally, and it would obviously fail to find it as I hadn't installed the pre-processor globally.

And I couldn't understand what was going on as every single one of the `devDependencies` in the `package.json` was already installed in the `node_modules` directory inside the root folder of the project. 
I kept running `karma start` from `AwesomeKarmaTests` folder without realizing that it was the global installation of karma that was being executed (silly me).

However after uninstalling `karma` from my global installation I started getting `/c/Users/fastasticUser/AppData/Roaming/npm/karma: No such file or directory` errors. That was when I realized my mistake.

Then I changed my approach. I started running my tests using the following command, explicitly specifying the path of the local installation of karma.

`./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js` from `AwesomeKarmaTests` directory. And as mentioned in several other posts, karma did pick its sibling packages and plugins.

So remember to use the **local** versions of the `karma` package when relying on other **locally** installed plugins or packages, else `karma` will have trouble identifying what you want it to do.