# Does Karma support source map files?

Tags: karma-runner

Is it possible to configure Karma to use source map files for stacktraces? I see that there are a few issues on GitHub which appear to have been closed? I can't however find any example of doing so.

If this is supported can someone illustrate an example config?

Answer (score 12):

In your karma.config.js file add

```
config.set({
files: [{
        pattern: '**/*.js.map',
        included: false
      },
...
});
```

This has worked for me, and files are now served by karma.

Comment: I also had to add the same entry for the mapped `angular.js` file to be served by the karma HTTP server.

Answer (score 7):

You need a preprocessor to look at source maps in karma: have a look at [`karma-sourcemap-loader`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-sourcemap-loader) to preprocess your data and locate the source map files.
A limitation of the library is that the source maps must be in the same folder as the js files, with the same name - but different extension of course.

Comment: Thanks! I've installed the loader, done the 'npm install' thing, added the preprocessor directive to my conf.js file but now I get "Can not load "sourcemap", it is not registered!", "Are you missing a plugin?"

Comment: You have to list all the plugins you are using in the configuration file: I had the same issue with the coverage one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069865/unable-to-run-coverage-with-karma?rq=1

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I've done the 'npm install karma-sourcempa-loader --save-dev', added a 'preprocessors' section as well as 'plugins' section, but I now get, "Cannot find plugin "karma-sourcemap-loader". Did you forget to install it?

Comment: karma-sourcemap-loader now supports inline source maps.  It had a bug until recently that would cause it to fail if the inline source map was followed by the unix-y blank line.

Comment: @cirrus did you solve the issue? i have the same problem/error

Comment: Nope. I never did. I'd been trying to get the support for TypeScript but despite several attempts following others' suggestions I never could, and had to manage without.

Comment: Note: I was unable to get this to work until I added the plugin to the list of plugins for Karma:
`plugins: [
    'karma-sourcemap-loader'
 ],`