# IntelliJ - karma tests: debugging sources with sourcemap

Tags: intellij-idea, karma-runner, webstorm

Scenario:

1. Build js sources > js_build.js with sourcemaps js_build.js.map
2. In IntelliJ run tests against js_build.js
3. All tests pass, config works
4. breakpoints in test files work

**Question:** How to get breakpoints in app source files working?

I believe I need to use sourcemaps in IntelliJ to remap built bundle back to sources, but I have not found a way to do it.

Karma.conf.js:

```
files: {[
      'js_build.js',
      {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/**/*.html', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/**/*Test.js', included: true}
]}
```

Comment: normally nothing special is needed - you just need to make sure to generate sourcemaps for both source and test files and make the m served by karma. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225322/does-karma-support-source-map-files

Comment: see also the tickets linked to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21165 for the list of known issues debugging karma with sourcemaps